# Minecraft says org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated only after updating, I tried updating graphics card

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, graphics-card

The title explains most of it. I have a lenovo G580, originally windows 8, since I upgraded to windows 10 I got a crash report. I tried downloading Intel's upgrading graphics card software, it didn't work(**That's how it's different from other questions!!**). What should I do to fix it?

Here is my crash report (the header is normal text with dashes under it):

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----  
// This is a token for 1 free hug. Redeem at your nearest Mojangsta:
[~~HUG~~]

Time: 10/3/15 10:59 AM  
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)  
    at   org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)  
    at ave.ap(SourceFile:534)  
    at ave.am(SourceFile:363)  
    at ave.a(SourceFile:310)  
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)  


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)  
    at ave.ap(SourceFile:534)  
    at ave.am(SourceFile:363)  

-- Initialization --  
Details:  
Stacktrace:  
    at ave.a(SourceFile:310)  
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)  

-- System Details --  
Details:  
    Minecraft Version: 1.8.8  
    Operating System: Windows 10 (x86) version 10.0  
    Java Version: 1.8.0_60, Oracle Corporation  
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation  
    Memory: 741648 bytes (0 MB) / 60702720 bytes (57 MB) up to 1037959168 bytes   (989 MB)  
    JVM Flags: 2 total; - XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G  
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0  
    Launched Version: 1.8.8  
    LWJGL: 2.9.4  
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.  
    GL Caps:   
    Using VBOs: No  
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.  
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)  
    Resource Packs:   
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null  
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)  
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Comment: My guess is that you need to update your graphics card drivers.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: That is not something we can tell you without more information, like what type of graphics card you're using, the type of computer you're using, and stuff like that.

Comment: The question already has that information!

Comment: If you're still getting that error, then you haven't done so.  That's how you fix that error.

Comment: Do you really want me to upload a YouTube video of  me trying to do it?

Comment: Window 10 and opengl doesn't support my graphics card